# JavaFX TextArea how to set text with automatic new line breaks

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

In my application, I'm using two `Tab`s. In the first one I placed a `HtmlEditor` and in the second one I placed a `TextArea`. HTML tab is default and when user is creating HTML input, he can switch to `TextArea` in order to see or change the HTML source code directly. I've added a listener to get the `htmlText` from the `HtmlEditor` and set it as text in `TextArea`, so user can easily switch between HTML and source mode. Here's my listener:

```
@FXML
private Tab htmlTab;

@FXML
private Tab sourceTab;

@FXML
private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

@FXML
private TextArea textEditor;

        htmlTab.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (htmlTab.isSelected()) {
                htmlEditor.setHtmlText(textEditor.getText());
            }
        }
    });

    sourceTab.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (sourceTab.isSelected()) {
                textEditor.setText(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
            }
        }
    });
```

It works fine, but `HtmlEditor` is breaking text into lines automatically. When I switch to `TextArea`, it's all in one line.

I thought about making a helper method which takes `TextArea` length attribute to count number of chars and adds new line character every "n" characters, but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Are you just looking for `textEditor.setWrapText(true);`?

Comment: 2 hours of research and it was so simple :) Thank you so much ! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you just want the text to wrap, use

```
textEditor.setWrapText(true);
```