# Best container to display copiable non-editable text without a border in Javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am looking for a GUI control element to store a multiline text. `TextArea textArea` works fine, but it has a border and doesn't fit `textArea` to text size unless some broilierplate code is added to compute `int rowCount` to set `textArea.setPrefRowCount(rowCount)`.

Other options like Label don't support copiable text.

What is the most suitable way to display selectable, non-editable text without a scrollbar/empty rows?

Comment: What about the `Label` using `\n` for newline?

Comment: A label is NOT copiable. Text comes from user input. Inserting line brakes manually = reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hmm, you'r right, Then did you try to use a `TextArea` with `setEdiatble(false)`, and removing all unnecessary components like scrollbar, and empty rows, and even set its background color to the parents background color?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797493/javafx-textarea-how-to-set-text-with-automatic-new-line-breaks This link may help you. Along with some CSS, you can make the border transparent.